# Prove a multivariable limit of a quotient using the epison-delta definition

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, epsilon-delta

I have to prove that $\displaystyle\lim_{(x,y)\to(1,0)} \frac{(x-1)^3\cos{y}}{(x-1)^2+y^2}=0$ using the epislon-delta definition of a limit.

Here's what I figured:
$\delta>|x-1| \Rightarrow \delta>(x-1)^2\Rightarrow \delta^3>|(x-1)^3|$. Also, $\delta>|y|\geq|cos{y}| \Rightarrow \delta^2>y^2$. So $\delta^4>|(x-1)^3\cos{y}|$ and $2\delta^2>|(x-1)^2+y^2|$. Obviously, $\delta^4>|\frac{(x-1)^3\cos{y}}{(x-1)^2+y^2}|$ if $(x-1)^2+y^2\geq1.$ But how do I account for it otherwise? I can't think of anything. I'm having issues proving the limits of quotients in general.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you denote $$f(x,y)=\frac{(x-1)^3\cos{y}}{(x-1)^2+y^2},$$ notice that

$$\vert f(x,y) \vert = \left\vert \frac{(x-1)^2}{(x-1)^2+y^2} \right\vert \vert \cos y \vert \vert x-1 \vert \le \vert x-1 \vert.$$

Then taking any $\epsilon \gt 0$, you have for $\delta = \epsilon$ and $\vert x - 1 \vert \lt \delta$:

$$\vert f(x,y) \vert \le \vert x - 1 \vert \lt \delta = \epsilon$$

which concludes the proof.

Comment: I am very sorry. I made a typo. It's fixed now.

Comment: Very well, thank you! I see what you did there. I was hoping for a more general answer to a quotionent limit. But I suppose there are none? You just rewrite the quotient to see which side is the larger, trying to bound it.

Comment: @BrKo14 You can have a more general answer. But you need at least to decide what means general? Rational maps? Rational and trigonometric maps? And if you go in that direction, the answer will be much more difficult to manage while finding a bounding map is quite easy here.